# ASP Form Recipient Error

Tags: email, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a form that when filled out and submitted, works fine. When the recipient replies to the sender though, the email actually goes to him instead of the intended party.

Below is the form. Help!

```vb
<%
Dim roomsanswer, fashionsanswer, commentsanswer, nameanswer, addressanswer, citystateanswer, zipanswer, phoneanswer, phone2answer, emailanswer, bccaddress, toaddress
If Request.Form("SendButton") <> "Send" Then
%>  
    <form action="<%=Request.ServerVariables("URL")%>" method="post" id="contactform">
      <h2>I am thinking about the windows in these rooms: (Please check as many answers as you like)</h2>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms" value="living Room" />
        Living Room
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms2" value="Dining Room" />
        Dining Room
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms2" value="Family Room" />
        Family Room
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms2" value="Bonus or Recreation Room" />
        Bonus or Recreation Room </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms2" value="Kitchen and/or Bathrooms" />
        Kitchen and/or Bathrooms
        <input type="checkbox" name="rooms2" value="Bedroom(s) " />
        Bedroom(s)</p>
      <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
      <h2>I am most interested in these window fashions:</h2>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Blinds" />
        Blinds
        <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Shades" />
        Shades
        <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Shutters" />
        Shutters
        <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Window Shadings" />
        Window Shadings (Silhouette, etc.)
        <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Draperies &amp; Top Treatments" />
      Draperies &amp; Top Treatments 
      <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Decorative Hardware &amp; Controls" />
      Decorative Hardware &amp; Controls
      <input type="checkbox" name="fashions" value="Sun &amp; Light Control Products" />
      Sun &amp; Light Control Products</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <h2>Here's what I'd like to do, or talk with the decorator about:&nbsp;<br />
          <textarea name="comments" cols="47" rows="9" wrap="physical" id="comments"></textarea>
      </h2>
      <p><strong>My Name:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="name" size="45" maxlength="50" />
      </p>
      <p><strong>My Address:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input name="address" type="text" id="address" size="45" maxlength="50" />
      </p>
      <p><strong>My City &amp; State:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input name="citystate" type="text" id="citystate" size="45" maxlength="50" />
      </p>
      <p><strong>My Zipcode:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" size="10" maxlength="5" />
      </p>
      <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
      <h2>My Telephones </h2>
      <p><strong>Daytime Telephone:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="phone" size="12" maxlength="15" />
      </p>
      <p><strong>Evening Telephone:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="phone2" size="12" maxlength="15" />
      </p>
      <p><strong>Email address:</strong>&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="email" size="45" maxlength="50" />
      </p>
      <p><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Send" name="SendButton" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="ClearButton" class="form" />
      </p>
    </form>
<%

'*** If the SendButton was clicked
'*** and there is a message to send,
'*** process the email and send it.
Else

'*** Create the message object.
Set Message = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

'*** Validate Input
commentsanswer = Request.Form("comments")
If commentsanswer = "" then
commentsanswer = "(No Additional Comments Given)"
End If

roomsanswer = Request.Form("rooms")
If roomsanswer = "" then
roomsanswer = "(No Rooms Given)"
End If

fashionsanswer = Request.Form("fashions")
If fashionsanswer = "" then
fashionsanswer = "(No Fashions Given)"
End If

nameanswer = Request.Form("name")
If nameanswer = "" then
nameanswer = "(No name given)"
End If

addressanswer = Request.Form("address")
If addressanswer = "" then
addressanswer = "(No address given)"
End If

citystateanswer = Request.Form("citystate")
If citystateanswer = "" then
citystateanswer = "(No city and state given)"
End If

zipanswer = Request.Form("zip")
If zipanswer = "" then
zipanswer = "(No zipcode given)"
End If

phoneanswer = Request.Form("phone")
If phoneanswer = "" then
phoneanswer = "(No phone number given)"
End If

phone2answer = Request.Form("phone2")
If phone2answer = "" then
phone2answer = "(No phone number given)"
End If

emailanswer = Request.Form("email")
If emailanswer <> "" then
toaddress = Request.Form("email")
bccaddress = "xxxxxx@aol.com"
End If

If emailanswer = "" then
emailanswer = "(No email address given)"
toaddress = "xxxxxx@aol.com"
bccaddress = ""
End If

'*** Set the from, to, and
'*** subject fields.

Message.From = "xxxxxx@aol.com"
Message.To = toaddress
Message.bcc = bccaddress & "," & ""
Message.Subject = "Customer Contact Information from Website"
Message.TextBody = vbcrlf & "Date and Time: " & Now() & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & " I am thinking about the windows in these rooms: " & roomsanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "I am most interested in these window fashions: " & fashionsanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Here's what I'd like to do, or talk with the decorator about: " & commentsanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & " My Name:" & vbcrlf & nameanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "My Address:" & vbcrlf & addressanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "My City & State:" & vbcrlf & citystateanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "My Zipcode:" & vbcrlf & zipanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "My Daytime Phone:" & vbcrlf & phoneanswer & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "My Evening Phone:" & vbcrlf & phone2answer

'*** If there is an error, 
'*** continue with the script.
On Error Resume Next

'*** Send the email message.
Message.Send

'*** If sending the message caused
'*** an error, then display the 
'*** message, else display a
'*** success message (or redirect
'*** to a different page).
If Err.Number = 0 Then
Response.Redirect("thankyou.html")
Else
Response.Write "Error: " & Err.Description
End If

'*** Clear out the message variable
Set Message = Nothing

'*** End of If for checking
'*** SendButton and message
'*** to send.
End If

%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181408 what you want?

Comment: I don't know how to incorporate that into what I have, but thanks.